# UINavigationBar styling without background images

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to find a way to modify the style of my UINavigationBar without using images. I want to create a flat UINavigationBar with a solid color. Is my only option to subclass UINavigationBar and draw the complete NavigationBar myself? I'm targeting iPhones running iOS 6.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `UINavigationBar appearance`

here you go, edit rgb values of colors as you need

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1/256.0 green:96/256.0 blue:149/256.0 alpha:1.0]];

 return YES;

}
```

**Note:** this wont effect bar button items , you have to look at `[[UIBarButtonItem appearance]` if you want to change buttons too

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:126/256.0 green:181/256.0 blue:55/256.0 alpha:1.0]];
```

Comment: Thanks @SpaceDust, that was exactly what I was looking for. I was about to ask you how to do the same thing for the bar button items :)

Comment: @Behzad you are welcome, edited my answer for a simple button code.